# Laravel return null when data save or update

Tags: php, laravel

I am using this code part many times without problem. But this time $success return null and i couldn't figure out. When i check database, i see User 1 is updated. Since it's saving there is no fillable problem. Also i tried save() function too. What am i missing? Thanks for help.

(Laravel version 5.2.45)

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->firstname = $request->firstname;
$user->lastname = $request->lastname;
$success= $user->update(); // Database update is successful
dd($success); // But return null
```

User model

```
<?php
namespace App;

use App\Presenters\UserPresenter;
use App\Services\Logging\UserActivity\Activity;
use App\Support\Authorization\AuthorizationUserTrait;
use App\Support\Enum\UserStatus;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
use CanResetPassword, AuthorizationUserTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

protected $dates = ['last_login', 'birthday'];
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = [];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
}
/**
 * Always encrypt password when it is updated.
 *
 * @param $value
 * @return string
 */
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}

public function gravatar()
{
    $hash = hash('md5', strtolower(trim($this->attributes['email'])));

    return sprintf("//www.gravatar.com/avatar/%s", $hash);
}

public function isUnconfirmed()
{
    return $this->status == UserStatus::UNCONFIRMED;
}

public function isActive()
{
    return $this->status == UserStatus::ACTIVE;
}

public function isBanned()
{
    return $this->status == UserStatus::BANNED;
}

public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class, 'city_id');
}
public function activities()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Activity::class, 'user_id');
}
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

public function getAuthpassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function getAuthIdentifierName()
{
    return $this->getKeyName();
}
public function verification()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Verification');
}
}
```

---

Update Question (New Try):

I tried empty controller with just update function. I still get failure.

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{

public function getEdit()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    return view('user.editprofile', compact('user'));
}

public function postEdit(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    $user->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $user->lastname = $request->lastname;
    if($user->update())
    {
        echo "Success";
    }
    echo "Fail"; // Print "Fail" but update was successful.
}

}
```

Comment: `$user->update()` returns false but update is successful? strange!

Comment: Yes Sanzeeb, that's why it's strange. I use success method every time and never had a problem like this. Also there is another function in Controller to update user's phone number and $success return true without problem. Same codes, one working, other not.

Comment: I have looked at the source code... and returning NULL is no option ( unless you have overidden your models update method )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out problem. There is a trait which override save and update function.

```
use App\Support\Authorization\AuthorizationUserTrait
```

Comment: I had a similar problem where $user->save would not return anything (so true/false, no error, NOTHING) which prevented me from checking for success/failure. Turns out a collaborator created a custom UserUpdated event/listener that was overriding any returns.

Answer (score 1):

When successfully inserted or updated records , laravel return true on success and false on failure and also you can check like this.

```
 if($user->save()){
     //do something when user is save 
 }else{
     // do something wehn user is not update
 }
```

or

```
if($user->update()){
     //do something when user is update 
 }else{
     // do something wehn user is not update
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Anuraj, i tried this too, but still returning null and go to else part

Comment: can u share your user model @GokhanDemirel ..
is there any code for your table and fillable ??
like this ..
 **protected $table = 'users';
 protected $fillable = ['username','password']; **

Comment: I added User model to my question

Comment: @GokhanDemirel 
 i can't figure it out exactly ..
but its a guess you need to authenticate user model via 
$user = Auth::user(); method and try...

Answer (score 0):

I usually did this for make sure is saved successfully

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    // save or update happen in here
    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    // something happen in here when error
}
```

for

```
DB::beginTransaction();
DB::commit();
DB::rollback();
```

is optional but I recommend it cause when anything bad happen in the middle it will rollback the saved data for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try update user using array. Like this

```
$user = User::find(1);
$dataToUpdate['firstname'] = $request->firstname;
$dataToUpdate['lastname'] = $request->lastname;
if($user->update($dataToUpdate))
{
    echo "Success";
}
echo "Fail"; // Print "Fail" but update was successful.
```

Also you can try to add:

```
protected $fillable = ['firstname', 'lastname'];
```

to your User.php Model